# Replace strings in file

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have to replace in a following manner

if the string is "string _countryCode" i have to replace it as "string _sCountryCode"

as you can see where there is **_ I replace it with _s followd be next character in capitals** ie _sC

more examples:

**string _postalCode to be replaced as string _sPostalCode**

**string _firstName  to be replace as string _sFirstName**

Please help.
Preferably answer in C# syntax

Comment: You want to *introduce* hungarian? ... *why?*

Comment: I agree with Marc. I'm not sure I can condone this activity by helping you :)

Comment: Well, if the 's' indicates e.g. "safe" (checked user input), it is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Well actually i have a particular naming convention to be used
 for example property fields must be _typeVariableName ,but i follow _variableName.


So i need to avoid typing again , and just write a program to change the convention( I have most of them as strings ,so i introduce _sPropertyName in place of _propertyName)..( In case of datetime it will be _dtDateOfJoining,,but these are few and can be done manually)

Comment: You should look into tools like fxCop/styleCop. Hungarian notation is frowned upon, you should consider naming convetions (if you need to define the type in the name) like _postalCodeStr instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand *why*, but perhaps something like:

```
static readonly Regex hungarian =
        new Regex(@"(string\s+_)([a-z])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...
string text = ...
string newText = hungarian.Replace(text, match =>
    match.Groups[1].Value + "s" +
    match.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper());
```

Note that the regex won't necessarily spot examples such as (valid C#):

```
string
    _name = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the strings are as you have shown, then you do not need to go for a regex. You can do this using Replace method of the string class.

Comment: yah sure..but how to make next character to be upper case.ie _c will have to be _sC.

I am a newbie..

Comment: yourString.Replace("_c", "_sC") would do that.

Comment: If you read the question the search term isn't fixed so this won't exactly to it. He will need a regex.

Comment: I guess it will. If all strings are like "string _something", he needs stringVariable.Replace("string _", "string _s"

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder ss=new StringBuilder(); 
         string concat="news_india";//or textbox1.text;          
         int indexs=concat.LastIndexOf("_")+1;//find "_" index 
         string find_lower=concat.Substring(indexs,1); 
         find_lower=find_lower.ToUpper(); //convert upper case 
         ss.Append(concat);
         ss.Insert(indexs,"s"); //s->what ever u like give "+your text+"
         ss.Insert(indexs+1,find_lower);
```

**try this..its will work**